# Validate the combination of 2 filed in same Entity

Tags: symfony

I have an entity called Note  , for every Note ther's *etudiant_id* and *evaluation_id* .
**I want that the combination of etudiant_id and evaluation_id should be unique** .
For exmple when i give him a 
`Note object1(etudiant_id=1,evaluation_id=1) and Note2 object2(etudiant_id=1,evaluation_id=1)` : this should throw an exception.
 but 
in case of :
`Note object1(etudiant_id=1,evaluation_id=2) and Note2 object2(etudiant_id=1,evaluation_id=1)` : this will not throw anything .
By the way i tried :`* @UniqueEntity(fields={"evaluation","etudiant"})` but this didnt work correcte.
Here's my Note Entity :

```
<?php

namespace EcoleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * Note
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"evaluation","etudiant"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="note")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EcoleBundle\Repository\NoteRepository")
 */
class Note
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="valeur", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $valeur;

      /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EcoleBundle\Entity\Evaluation", inversedBy="notes")
    */
    private $evaluation;
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EcoleBundle\Entity\Etudiant", inversedBy="notes")
    */
    private $etudiant;
```

Comment: It sounds like you need here custom validation constraint. Depending on your version, this link might be useful :http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only one @Entity annotation. Try to substitute with this and clean the cache

```
/**
 * Note
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EcoleBundle\Repository\NoteRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"evaluation","etudiant"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="note")
 */
```